# jqueryUI not show description

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to customize the look of the autocomplete elements in JQuery to show value with name ( desc ). but desc didn't show it self.Thank you for advice.

This is how json echo from my php look like.

```
[{"value":"normal grade size A KW\/KA125","label":"6","desc":"normal grade size A KW\/KA125"},{"value":"normal grade size B KW\/KA125","label":"7","desc":"normal grade size B KW\/KA125"}]
```

My html.

```
<div id="package-label">Select a package:</div>
<input id="package" />
<input type="hidden" id="package-id"/>
<p id="package-description"></p>
```

My code.

```
  $(function() {
    $("#package").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: 'search.php',
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#package").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#package").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#package-id").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#package-description").html(ui.item.desc);
            return false;
        }
    })
        .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would advise reviewing the Source here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Then use code like:

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  return $("<li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<div><a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a></div>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Result should have the following format:

```
<li>
  <div>
    <a>Label<br>Description</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Unsure why you are using `a`. I would not advise this. Would advise the following:

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  return $("<li>")
    .append("<div><span class='itemLabel'>" + item.label + "</span><span class='itemDesc'>" + item.desc + "</span></div>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

And use the following CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete .itemLabel {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: reviewing from doc again and that work. ( But don't know why mine won't work tho ) Thanks !